# Can't find property when using PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer @Bean

Tags: java, spring, properties

We're configuring a new Spring application and we're trying to nail down how to keep our application properties different for each environment. We're using PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer @Beans with @Profile to specfify which property file to use:

```
public abstract class BaseConfig implements InitializingBean, DisposableBean {

    private static final String LOCAL_CONFIG = "local/application.properties";
    private static final String DEV_CONFIG = "development/application.properties";
    private static final String STAGING_CONFIG = "staging/application.properties";
    private static final String PRODUCTION_CONFIG = "production/application.properties";

    @Bean
    @Profile("development")
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer developmentPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        System.out.println("config'ing dev");
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        configurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource(DEV_CONFIG));
        return configurer;
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("staging")
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer stagingPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        System.out.println("config'ing staging");
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        configurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource(STAGING_CONFIG));
        return configurer;
    }

    // and so on...

}
```

We add an environment property to the command line that does seem to be selecting these profiles correctly:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active="development"
```

We see this in the logs when `BaseConfig` is scanned:

```
config'ing dev
2015-07-24T15:19:09,529 {} [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO  o.s.c.s.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from class path resource [development/application.properties]
```

When we try to get a property out of one of the files, it's not in an @Autowire'd Environment or in the ApplicationContext's environment:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { 
        "com.myapp.jpa.domain", "com.myapp.jpa.repositories" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = "file:/my/home/dir/db.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
public class JpaConfig extends BaseConfig {

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
        String testProperty = environment.getProperty("test.property");
        logger.info("test.property from autowired environment: " + testProperty);

        ApplicationContext ctx = new GenericApplicationContext();
        Environment env = ctx.getEnvironment();
        boolean contains = env.containsProperty("test.property");
        logger.info("Does my environment contain the 'test.property' property? " + contains);
        logger.info("test.property from context: " + env.getProperty("test.property"));

        // ...
    }
}
```

Both of these statements print a null property. In summary, it looks like the `application.properties` file that I want to be read is, in fact, being read but that those properties aren't available in the `Environment`. What am I doing wrong? I suspect there's something I'm missing to hook up the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer Bean once it's been created.

```
2015-07-24T15:19:09,730 {} [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO  x.y.z.JpaConfig - test.property from autowired environment: null
2015-07-24T15:19:09,731 {} [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO  x.y.z.JpaConfig - Does my environment contain the 'test.property' property? false
2015-07-24T15:19:09,731 {} [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO  x.y.z.JpaConfig - test.property from context: null
```

---

EDIT - Oops. I forgot to paste in here what `development/application.properties` looks like:

```
test.property=from_development
```

---

EDIT - Someone asked about the active profiles. I am setting them using the `-D` property of the Java command. If it wasn't set, the proper method in BaseConfig wouldn't be running but it is. I added the code below to prove that the active profile is, in fact, being set:

```
for ( String activeProfile : environment.getActiveProfiles() ) {
    logger.info("active profile: " + activeProfile);
}
```

Which produces:

```
2015-07-24T16:02:48,179 {} [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO  c.d.c.c.j.JpaConfig - active profile: development
```

Comment: Can you try using `classpath:` instead of `file:`? for `@PropertySource`

Comment: Well, the `@PropertySource` isn't where the properties are supposed to be coming from in this case. The properties we want should be coming from the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer ` `Bean` that was created in `BaseConfig`. The `@PropertySource` is working as intended, if that matters.. We use properties from that later in the `dataSource` method.

Comment: But you shouldn't ship all those properties in the same project, or at least, it's not common. I guess you might want to load one file name and configure your beans base on the actual Spring profile. Have a look at [this](https://bitbucket.org/vadimvera/spring-mvc/)

Comment: Actually, we want to avoid creating different artifacts for each environment. We want one environment with an env variable switch to choose which set of properties we use for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like I was doing this all wrong. I started down the right path but then got derailed for some reason. The right way to do this is to have `@Configuration` classes for each environment and have each point to different `application.properties` files:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("development")
@PropertySource("classpath:development/application.properties")
public class DevelopmentConfig extends BaseConfig {
}
```

And:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("production")
@PropertySource("classpath:production/application.properties")
public class ProductionConfig extends BaseConfig {
}
```

Then, you specify the profile that should be used on the command line when starting the server:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active="development"
```